# Allow plugins for local files

Tags: google-chrome, pdf, plugins

Chrome is my standard viewer for PDF files, but it is also configured to "Let me choose when to run plugin content".

When viewing PDF files in the internet, I can choose to allow the domain in the top right corner. A PDF on the local file system only yields the option to allow exactly the path to the current PDF.

I would like to allow all plugins to run when the domain starts with `file:///`.

I tried to enter the regex `file://[*.]` into the options menu here: `chrome://settings/contentExceptions#plugins`, but it is not accepted.

Is there a way to do it? Perferrably without extensions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following worked for me: `file:///*`