# How can I open local PDFs with Google Scholar PDF Reader?

Tags: windows, google-chrome, pdf

I like the [Google Scholar PDF Reader](https://chromewebstore.google.com/detail/google-scholar-pdf-reader/dahenjhkoodjbpjheillcadbppiidmhp?utm_medium=blog&utm_source=scholar.googleblog.com&utm_campaign=launch) (Chrome extension) to read papers.  It works well on web links, e.g. https://arxiv.org/pdf/2402.19427.pdf. How can I open local PDFs (i.e., PDF saves on my laptop's disk) with the Google Scholar PDF Reader? I use Windows 10.

---

Google Scholar PDF Reader:

[image]

Default PDF viewer when I  open local PDFs:

[image: dv]

Comment: While your screenshot implies things, you don't actually clearly state this: Have you tried setting the Chrome browser as your default PDF handler? Also, have you checked out this old question: https://superuser.com/questions/940408/allow-plugins-for-local-files

Answer (score 1):

Go to Google Scholar PDF Reader extension settings (chrome://extensions/?id=dahenjhkoodjbpjheillcadbppiidmhp) and enable "allow access to file URLs":

[image]

Thanks [music2myear](https://superuser.com/users/74026/music2myear) for the pointer to it.

Answer (score 0):

Two possibilities come to mind:

1. Change your computer settings for .pdf viewing (includes Windows pc and OS X options):  Check out [this question and answer](https://superuser.com/questions/199382/make-chrome-always-open-pdfs-itself) as it might help.
2. Less technical work around: Email the local pdfs to yourself and then open via web-browser email client. (e.g., Make a gmail account if you don't already have one.  Email your local .pdf to your gmail account.  Using Chrome, log in to your gmail account and open the attached .pdfs from there. Chrome should then use its extensions to view the .pdfs.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).